# fallback connection to internet

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, hotspot, connection-sharing

I already searched the forum for similar problems, but I was not able to solve my issue.

This is the scenario (as detailed in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muRBG.png)):

[image: the picture]

I have a classic home network connected to the internet via a modem/router/AP; in the LAN (192.168.120.0/24) there are some wired and some wireless devices (all running Linux): among them a Raspberry with two NICs: the ethernet one connected to the LAN, and the wifi one (a dongle) normally unused.

Sometimes the ISP connection drops, and I would like to have fallback connectivity using my smartphone as a hot spot; the idea would be to connect to it the wifi NIC of the Raspberry, and then use its wired NIC to share this connectivity with the rest of the LAN (while the inter-LAN connectivity remains the same)

I tried to set a bridge "wireless-to-wired" network on the raspberry, but with no success (even trying to set the 4addr functionality, that doesn't work, even if apparently the wifi dongle supports it); I also tried to set a "shared to other computers" network, always on the raspberry.. but I'm not able to properly set the parameters both on the raspberry and on the other clients

For sure I'm not so expert on the network configuration.. so I would like to have some explanation on how to proceed (and troubleshoot)

Comment: You're essentially trying to run 2 networks over the same hardware... which seems quite tricky

Comment: You more than likely need a failover router.  I have not seen a model that accepts a smartphone hotspot as input.

Comment: Some ISPs do provide a router that can failover to a mobile network if the primary connection goes down. In your case I suspect that you should actually have your entire network routed through the Raspberry Pi so that you have a single network and one device handling failover. In your current layout every device has to individually detect a failure then somehow switch to the gateway provided by the Pi. Doing it all on the Pi would be somewhat easier https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78787/ but would make the Pi itself a bottleneck.

Comment: Sorry.. I thought that the image was clear enough.. probably doesn't... 
for Journeyman Geek: it is not on the same hardware... the raspberry has two NICs... this is the device that should act as a bridge between the hotspot network, and the LAN

Comment: for John: I am not asking the "main" router to do the trick.. in the fallback situation, it should act only as a AP, no more as a router

Comment: for Mokubai:  I can't/wan't afford a solution with an additional mobile network subscription, when I have already my phone with plenty of GB/month, for the rare occasions in which the main connection fails;   you are right: the RP is a bottleneck.. but is needed only on those rare ccasions.. and in that case for me is not a problem to reconfigure, for 3-4 days, the whole fleet of devices in order to use the RP as a gateway

Comment: @scimmiettarossa Mokubai is right, you will need to add a failover functionality to your main router. Unless your router doesn't have this function you need to look for a new firmware or a new router. There are software solutions out there as well. You don't have to get an additional subscription. You will need an AP connected to the hotspot which in turn is connected to the *fail-over WAN port* of your router.

Comment: nevertheless.. I think that using the raspberry as a bridge should be possible...  not efficient, not smart, perhaps... but I need help in this.. let's say it is just an academic interest, to learn something...

Comment: @scimmiettarossa yes, you can use the rasberry as an AP connected to the failover port of you router. Or as the host for a software router.

Comment: @albin: about the second option.. I'm stuck.. I was not able to set a bridge connection between the wifi  and the wired NICs on the raspberry.. I read something about the impossibility to do it without setting 4addr on the wifi NIC, that seems impossible on my device... So I tried to use the port forwarding, instead, but I do not know how to proceed..

Comment: @scimmiettarossa not sure what you mean, please edit the question and add your info there. BTW this won't work anyway if you don't have a failover WAN port on your router. I added an answer.

Comment: Running OpenWrt or DD-WRT on your Raspberry would allow you to do this, but you'd need to manually configure it via SSH to modify the `swport` config to reverse the interfaces and change the firewall from LAN to WAN and vice versa. While this could be automated, I'd recommend manually configuring this each time via SSH and a script, as it would be detrimental to every downstream device if an error occurred and the firewall wasn't changed from LAN to WAN when switching ports - since there's only two ports, safest way would be to modify the configs via a script then reboot to apply.

Comment: @JW0914: I will explore this way!

Answer (score 1):

**For automatic failover,** you can not just connect a second internet connection and add it to your network via a switch. This will cause all sorts of problems like having two DHCP servers etc. (if you don't use DHCP on the hotspot, you will have to configure all clients manually, which probably isn't a solution either).

What you need is to **add a failover functionality to your** (main) **router** (including a failover WAN port). If your router doesn't have this function you need to look for new firmware or a new router. I would guess there are software solutions out there as well, even some you might be able to use with your Raspberry Pie if you don't want to buy new hardware.

Other than that you will need some WLAN bridge (e.g. your Rasberry Pie) that connects to the hotspot and is also connected to the fail-over WAN port of your router.

**Alternatively, as a manual failover,** you can use any device that can connect to the hotspot of your mobile phone and is capable of sharing its internet connection over a wired network (could be your Rasberry Pie). It will essentially become your new "router" but you will have to "disable" your main one (more specifically its DCHP function), and make all clients refresh the DHCP lease so they "connect" to the new "router".

Alternatively, you could setup the device to share its internet connection via `192.168.120.1` (but then you have to change the IP from your main router).

Comment: :all my devices have already  static IP, so no DHCP is messing up.    
     
Your second solution is exactly what I would like to do, but I'm not able to make it work: in particular I would like to understand how to make a bridge (if possible, but it seems not), or a NAT translation (and thi is what more I need help into)

Comment: @scimmiettarossa First you need to decide on a configuration. A bridge won't do you any good: the clients use `192.168.120.1` as the default gateway but `192.168.70.1` will be your new router. This won't work. You will either have to change the client's default gateway or set `192.168.120.1` as the IP address of the eth interface on your pie (in this case your router can't keep `192.168.120.1` or you will cause an IP conflict).

Comment: the configuration I decided for is the one in the picture... and what you are saying is exactly what I do not understand: the new "router" is 192.168.70.1, the raspberry has the wifi NIC as 192.168.70.30... why the raspberry itself can not "bridge" between  subnets 192.168.70.x and 192.168.120.x? I expected that , by setting the gateway of all the clients to 192.168.120.100 (i.e. the raspberry wired NIC), everything should work.. what am I missing

the original router should act only as access point, in this case (obviously by changing its settings)

Comment: @scimmiettarossa the default gateway must point directly to the router and it needs to be in the same subnet. You need to add routing capabilities to your Pie in order to connect the two different subnets (just a bridge won't do). The Pie needs to route all incoming internet traffic to `192.168.70.1` via its `wlan` interface.

Comment: @scimmiettarossa Assuming the OS of your Pie has the option I still think the function to share its internet connection would be the easiest choice for you (you might add a DHCP to your network this way, depending on the configuration, but since all your clients have static setup this shouldn't matter). This way you won't have to bother with a manual router setup.

Comment: you said that I have to route the internet traffic to 192.168.70.1 via its wlan... I have two questions: a) as I wrote above, this routing is exactly what I am confused about: I do not know enough about iptables etc to do that autonomously.. B) 70.1 is the IP of the wired interface.. not the wlan (the wlan interface is the one connectd to internet).. is that a problem?

Comment: @scimmiettarossa a) That's why I advised you to use an "internet sharing feature", this will take care of manual setups b) This is not what your diagram says, please correct the question (to avoid confusion)

Comment: opppsss. you're right about b). the image is correct.. I got confused in my last commentit's my comment.. 70.1 is the wireless interface to the smartphone, i.e. to the internet (I cannot edit the comment)

Comment: @scimmiettarossa No, you can't edit comments, that's why I wrote to edit the question, not the comment ;) in general, you should add information, not into comment (since they can and should be deleted after a while).